# How do I resolve "Failed to parse remote port from server"?

Tags: vscode-remote

I'm setting up a new remote host and every time I initiate it I get the following error output. How can I resolve this issue?

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>
> Linux Destiny 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1 (2019-04-12) x86_64
>
> The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
> the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
> individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
>
> Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
> permitted by applicable law.
>
> mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>
> bash: cannot set terminal process group (3202): Inappropriate ioctl for device
> bash: no job control in this shell
>
> mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>
> Installing...
> Downloading with wget
>
> WARNING: tar exited with non-0 exit code
>
> Found running server...
>
> *
>
> - Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> - as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> - 
>
> cat: /root/.vscode-remote/.473af338e1bd9ad4d9853933da1cd9d5d9e07dc9.log: No such
> file or directory
>
> Server did not start successfully. Full server log:
> cat: /root/.vscode-remote/.X.log51ec4692-
> 4da4-4ec0-b613-5a3563034cf1====
> : No such file or directory

"install" terminal command done
Received install output: : No such file or directory
Failed to parse remote port from server output: : No such file or directory

Answer (score 18):

If the server fails to shut down properly, sometimes it leaves dangling lockfiles. This can cause startup to fail and produce the "Failed to parse remote port from server output" error message. In this case the solution is to simply to delete the lockfiles:

```
.vscode-server/bin/[:xdigit:]*/vscode-remote-lock.*
```

Comment: In my case it happened randomly after a disconnect, but thank you it worked! VSCode team needs to add a more descriptive error

Comment: In my case there was no `vscode-remote-lock.*` file so I removed the entire `.vscode-server/bin` folder and it worked

Answer (score 7):

There are many causes for this problem,

- First, ensure the ssh is working, whatever you can restart the ssh

```bash
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

- Then, delete the lock files

```bash
rm -rf ~/.vscode-server/bin/**
```

- Finally, retry connecting

Comment: Upvoted because you put the complete path in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue. It appears I had two other server agents running incorrectly. I killed both server agents using kill (PID) and removed the ".vscode_remote" directory from the user home directory. Then I reinitialized remote-ssh from Visual Studio Code. Successfully connected!

Comment: How did you find the PIDs for the server agents?

Comment: > How did you find the PIDs for the server agents?https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196306/8366223

Answer (score 2):

I ssh'd onto the remote server (Linux) and then deleted both directories as follows:

```
rm -r .vscode-server.backup2022-04-03T16:20:18-05:00

rm -r .vscode-server
```

Answer (score 1):

On the remote machine you do not have a **tar** file installed. It's in the log output

> Installing... Downloading with wget
>
> WARNING: **tar exited with non-0 exit code**

so under a root run:

```
apt-get install tar
```

or with sudo, if you have a user with sudoers configured:

```
sudo apt-get install tar
```

Comment: Tar was installed. i think this issue is related to bash script not treated as a terminal.

 "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because Visual Studio Code was looking for my *.vscode-server* directory in the wrong location (it was in a custom location due to restrictions on where files can be saved). This can be fixed by using *[How to change vscode-server directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613523/how-to-change-vscode-server-directory)*. Specifically, add

```
"remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": true,
"remote.SSH.serverInstallPath":{
    "hostname":"/path/to/.vscode-server/.."
}
```

to your *settings.json* file.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63196023/21704543) is to use the uninstaller of remote-ssh extension. First, use [Ctrl + P] and type [> remote-ssh uninstall]. Then, selecte the `uninstall` option and choose the server where this error occurred. The relevant lockfile will be automatically deleted. If there is a permission error in the VSCODE [output] window, you can use `sudo` permission to remotely delete this file through ssh.

Comment: Worked for me thanks. The problem was on VSCode Server side.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue and my workaround was to provide proper rights to the `home` or `user` folder, so Visual Studio Code can create a remote folder and do the required installation on it.

Example:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/
```

In this case, I have provided all rights to my home folder ([777](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/)) and it worked like a charm for all the users.

Comment: To me, it's a permission issue as well. Thanks for the hint

Comment: 777 is (U)ser / owner can read, can write and can execute. (G)roup can read, can write and can execute. (O)thers can read, can write and can execute. What are the security implications?

Comment: Actually, vscode required write permissions ,so you can provide right permissions only.

Comment: While this may resolve a permission issue, this enables everyone on the server to access all user home directories, i.e., in general, **this is dangerous**! Rather fix permissions for the directory within the corresponding user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else encounters the same issue: I had an instance where the remote target didn't have any space left on the device. After extending the root volume of the target machine, the connection worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it wasn't working because of the server asking for a new password when starting a session. I opened a new default terminal (not the Visual Studio Code terminal, but your OS default terminal, like [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), and so on). And I used the `ssh` command to log in. I logged in successfully and changed the password. Then I tried connecting with the new password and it worked, because the server didn't asked for a password change now.

Command:

```
ssh username@IP
```

Enter the password and you'll get asked to change the password. Change the password and try connecting again with new password using the SSH Visual Studio Code extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you authorize by ssh-key, also check the value of the *User* parameter in Visual Studio Code's SSH configuration. *User* must have a matching key in file *~/.ssh/authorized_keys* on the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

[Sachin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979701/how-do-i-resolve-failed-to-parse-remote-port-from-server/70488069#70488069) directed me in the right direction. Visual Studio Code needs permissions in order to create some files, but instead of giving [777](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/) permissions to your home folder (which can be dangerous), you can just [chown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) the user that wants to log in (the user for me was *ubuntu*):

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu /home
```

> I also got the same issue and my workaround was to provide proper rights to the home or user folder, so Visual Studio Code can create a remote folder and do the required installation on it.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for my case:

1. Connect to your server through a terminal (vscode terminal, cmd etc)!
2. Remove `vscode-server` from `/home/user_name/` folder. (`rm -r /home/user_name/.vscode-server`)
3. Try connect from VS code again!

The server will be re-installed. However, you loose  config, meta data etc.

Answer (score 0):

For folks with a Mac OS X host, I ran into this error message and I suspect it's caused by Mac's change to ZSH for the default shell (See here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050).

- Go System settings, click on Users & Groups
- Control-click the user name you want to change the login shell for and click on advanced options
- Change the login shell to /bin/bash
- On the host kill all servers:

  ```
  kill -9 $(ps aux | grep vscode-server | grep $USER | grep -v grep |
  awk '{print $2}')
  ```
- On the host delete all server downloads:

  ```
  rm -rf $HOME/.vscode-server # Or ~/.vscode-server-insiders
  ```

After doing this I was able to reconnect (maybe took one or two attempts).

NOTE: The kill and rm -rf commands are from [these vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_cleaning-up-the-vs-code-server-on-the-remote)

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to SSH into a remote host, if you encounter an issue where the connection fails with an error message, it's possible that the host's key has changed since the last connection. One solution to resolve this issue is to remove the entry associated with the remote host from the `known_hosts` file.

Here are the steps to follow:

1. Locate the known_hosts file on your local machine. This file is typically located in the `.ssh` directory within your home directory.
2. Open the `known_hosts` file using a text editor.
3. Search for the entry corresponding to the remote host that you are trying to SSH into.
4. Delete the entire line containing the entry for the remote host.
5. Save the changes to the `known_hosts` file.
6. After removing the outdated entry from the known_hosts file, you should be able to SSH into the remote host without encountering any further issues.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Add port to your configuration file:

Host hostname 
Port 22 
User username

Step 2:  Go to menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Open settings.json file*. Search for lockfilesInTmp and check the box next to that