# How to kill VSCode remote services on Ubuntu Host

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I just updated VSCode Remote Insider and I can't connect to my host through VSCode anymore.

I tried to uninstall my local VSCode Insider and restart it, but it didn't help. Then, I removed the `.vscode-remote-insider` directory on my host. However, VSCode remote can't re-install a remote service as the old one is still running. The following is the output from my local VSCode client.

```
remote-ssh@0.44.0
win32 x64
SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote", attempt 1
SSH Resolver called for host: 121
Setting up SSH remote "121"
Using commit id "c089daa858f34631f5f827ff8a0313bf1e2ded6d" and quality "insider" for server
Testing ssh with ssh -V
ssh exited with code: 0
Got stderr from ssh: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
Install and start server if needed
> 
> Installing to /home/***/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/c089daa858f34631f5f827ff8a0313bf1e2ded6d...
> 
> Downloading with wget
> 
> Download complete
> 
> Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> 
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> Server did not start successfully. Full server log >>>
> <<< End of server log
> cat: /home/***/.vscode-server-insiders/.c089daa858f34631f5f827ff8a0313bf1e2ded6d.log: No such file or directory
> cat: /home/***/.vscode-server-insiders/.c089daa858f34631f5f827ff8a0313bf1e2ded6d.log: No such file or directory
> cat: /home/***/.vscode-server-insiders/.c089daa858f34631f5f827ff8a0313bf1e2ded6d.log: No such file or directory
> 
"install" terminal command done
Received install output: cat: /home/***/.vscode-server-insiders/.c089daa858f34631f5f827ff8a0313bf1e2ded6d.log: No such file or directory
Failed to parse remote port from server output: cat: /home/shawnguo/.vscode-server-insiders/.c089daa858f34631f5f827ff8a0313bf1e2ded6d.log: No such file or directory
```

The biggest trouble is that I can't kill the processes of VSCode on my host as they could always produce a new process when the old one is killed.

Comment: @Melebius killing a process is a generic OS thing, and not specific to programming

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes but VS Code Server is still somewhat specific: It’s a [set of processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60420090/711006) and the client offers [an integrated way to kill the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57494961/711006).

Answer (score 114):

Try to kill vs code-remote host
through the command after pressing ctrl + shift + p and enter

```
Remote-SSH: kill VS Code Server on Host...
```

Then choose your host

Comment: Also if there are new never-existed-before problems with remote VS Code like entering SSH password many times but without success, after killing the process as mentioned above, delete the `.vscode` folder in the home directory of the remote.

Comment: The current VSCode version as of this date returns an error on the kill. It seems this is broken at the moment. "kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]"

Comment: Yes, you would think this would work, but it did not work for me either ... I had to use the other solutions to `kill` all the `.vscode-server` processes ... related issues: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5813 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/9147

Answer (score 25):

It works for me just killing the process called "node":

```
 killall node
```

Of course, it's not a perfect solution, just a work around.

Comment: If you kill all node processes it can affect to other node apps running.

Comment: ps uxa | grep .vscode-server | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

Comment: @inselberg you saved me for typing, thanks! ;)

Comment: @inselberg is a lifesaver. This https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5813 is related as "Remote-SSH: kill VS Code Server on Host..." doesn't (always) seem to work.

Comment: @Melebius i can't it's closed... But feel free to reopen it and publish mine ;)

Comment: @inselberg Thank you for mentioning that. The question has passed reopen voting, so you can post your answer now.

Answer (score 19):

`ps aux | grep .vscode-server | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill`

If that somehow doesn't work, you can escalate by changing `kill` to `kill -9` at the end, to force-kill the process with a SIGKILL instead of a regular SIGTERM; but in my experience the regular SIGTERM is enough.

And as @keith-hanlan points out, going straight to "... kill -9 is a terrible reflex and should only ever be used as a last resort. Since, by design, the signal cannot be caught, processes are unable to perform any cleanup activity. Depending on the process, this can leave a system in an unhealthy state; files can be closed without buffers being flushed, detached child processes can be orphaned, the list goes on. Well-written processes should respond appropriately to SIGTERM. By all means, use SIGKILL if necessary - but only after first trying other means."

Comment: Excellent!  That's what I needed to do in order for changes in the user groups to take effect

Comment: Using `kill -9` is a terrible reflex and should only ever be used as a last resort. Since, by design, the signal cannot be caught, processes are unable to perform any cleanup activity. Depending on the process, this can leave a system in an unhealthy state; files can be closed without buffers being flushed, detached child processes can be orphaned, the list goes on.

Well-written processes should respond appropriately to SIGTERM.

By all means, use SIGKILL if necessary - but only after first trying other means.

Comment: It's a shame that you turned this comment into an answer, with the comment having 50+ votes and this having less than 10 votes. Upvoting to get more exposure and this worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: If you are killing the codeserver for a particular user you can do `ps uxa | grep .vscode-server | awk '{print $2}' | grep myuser | xargs kill -9`

Comment: Nope... I this case -9 is the exact way. Proposing to use a simple kill shows only that someone never had to deal with a hanging remote service of vscode or didnt understand why the "script" isn't targeting a single process. If the remote server hangs vscode will respawn a huge amount of new remote services. So "kill vs kill -9"  is the answer to an other question.

Answer (score 3):

`pkill -9 vscode-server` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

After submitting an issue on their github page, I took some of the help from above and wrote this script for running as a cron every day at 4am, as I'd rather not go back to just using vim for everything:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $kill_at_hours = 4;
my @kill_pids = ();
my $ps_path = "./vspx.log";
my $look_for_cmd = "ps -eo pid,etime,comm | egrep 'code-[a-f0-9]{10}|node' > $ps_path";
my $sys = system($look_for_cmd);

open my $ps_file, "<", $ps_path;
while (<$ps_file>) {
    if ($_ =~ m/^\s*(\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+/) {
        my ($pid, $elapsed) = ($1, $2);
        my ($d, $h) = (0, 0);
        if ($elapsed =~ m/^(?:(\d{1,2}):)?\d{1,2}:\d\d/) {
            $h = $1;
        } elsif ($elapsed =~ m/^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2}):\d\d:\d\d$/) {
            ($d, $h) = ($1, $2);
        }
        my $total_hours = ($d * 24) + $h;
        if ($total_hours > $kill_at_hours) {
            my $process = `ps --no-headers $pid`;
            chomp $process;
            if ($process =~ m#
                    \.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-[a-f0-9]{40}/server/node |
                    \.vscode-server/code-[a-f0-9]{40}
                 #x) {
                push @kill_pids, $pid;
            }
        }
    }
}
close $ps_file;

for my $pid (@kill_pids) {
    my $kill_cmd = "kill $pid";
    my $sys = system($kill_cmd);
}
```

Comment: Can you link to the Issue here?

Comment: Yes, sorry for just now seeing this. Issue posted here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/9147