# VS Code ssh; server install path

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, ssh

I am trying to change the VS Code server folder install location. The functionality was recently implemented and I've found the following references [[1]](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/472), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613523/how-to-change-vscode-server-directory).
However, I have not been able to implement it myself and in trying I get the following error message:

```
C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: remote.ssh.serverinstallpath 
C:\\Users\\username/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

The config file is constructed in the following way

```
"remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {"hostname": "/test/location"}

Host hostname
  HostName hostname
  User username
```

NOTE: I have obscured the connection as 'hostname' and the user as 'username'

Answer (score 9):

This config is for vscode's `settings.json` file (not `.ssh/config`):

e.g on Windows, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)". Then, you can add the following lines at the end.

```
"remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {
    "<host>": "/test/location"
}
```

Alternative, if you want do it via settings UI:

1. File > Preferences > Settings
2. Filter: `@ext:ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh install`
3. Under "Server Install Path" > Add Item

   - Item = `<host>`
   - Value = `/test/location`

Comment: Can you give an example for `<host>` It's not clear whether it refers to the SSH hostname or some other identifier.

Comment: If anyone comes across this question, the "Host" refers to the same value specified in your SSH config file "Host" field.