# How to change vscode server install directory when using remote tunnels extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using [vscode remote tunnels](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels) to access a research Linux machine that is not directly accessible via SSH.

The issue is that due to the particular setup of the machine, the home directory is very limited in size and one is expected to store all data on a network drive or separately mounted disk.

As such I need to install the vscode server that I use to access the machine onto a non-default location outside the home directory.

Searching for how to set this up, I found [this related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73540611/11228478). However it describes using the SSH remote development extensions and applying the suggested change did not change the install directory of the vscode server.

Comment: I downloaded the extension VSIX, looked at the package.json, and the only setting the extension directly contributes seems to be `remote.tunnels.alwaysUpdateCLI`.