# Failed to parse remote port from server output

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, jupyter-notebook, remote-access

I want to connect to jupyterhub server of my organization with vscode's `Remote SSH`, however it crashed with this report:

```
[17:48:27.180] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 56752 "jupyterhub.whatever.com" bash
[17:48:27.183] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:48:27.575] > 系统无法执行指定的程序。
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:48:27.576] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[17:48:28.857] "install" terminal command done
[17:48:28.858] Install terminal quit with output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:48:28.858] Received install output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[17:48:28.858] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[17:48:28.859] Resolver error: Error: 
    at g.Create (c:\Users\k6789\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:585222)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\k6789\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:583874)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\k6789\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:681023)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async c:\Users\k6789\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:643908
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\k6789\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:647224)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\k6789\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:644958)
    at async c:\Users\k6789\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:726917
[17:48:28.863] ------
```

And this is my SSH config:

```
Host jupyterhub.whatever.com
  HostName jupyterhub.whatever.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  User MyUserName
```

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979701/how-do-i-resolve-failed-to-parse-remote-port-from-server) can't help me, so how to solve the problem?

Comment: The question you linked is trying to set up a new SSH connection. I think your issue, on the other hand, was due to some kind of mishandled server exit.

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the content in your C:/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts and connect against the same host.
I had a similar problem and it's looks like Visual Studio creates a new config file.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with VS Code. I was able to resolve it by using SSH from a terminal and running the following on the host:

```
rm -f .vscode-server/*.log
```