# How can I use a proxy for remote development with VS Code using SSH?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, ssh, proxy, cygwin

I've followed [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) documentation and have successfully installed the Microsoft "Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH" extension and was able to connect remotely to my laptop. But the issue is, my connectivity is limited. If I want to SSH to a WAN address, I have to use a proxy. For example if I want to SSH to my VPS, I have to use this command on Cygwin on my Windows machine:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p" root@x.x.x.x
```

But how do I configure VSCode to use a proxy for the SSH connection? Is there a way to modify the SSH command that VSCode runs so that I can include the `nc` command so that it uses my proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that when you add a new ssh host, you can enter an ssh command to use instead of just a host name.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_remember-hosts-and-advanced-settings

> Start by selecting **Remote-SSH: Add New SSH Host...** from the Command Palette (`F1, Ctrl+Shift+P`) or clicking on the Add New icon in the SSH Remote Explorer in the Activity Bar.
>
> You'll then be asked to enter the SSH connection information. You can either enter a host name
>
> Or the full `ssh` command you would use to connect to the host from the command line.
>
> Finally, you'll be asked to pick a config file to use. You can also set the `"remote.SSH.configFile"` property in your User `settings.json` file if you want to use a different config file than those listed. The extension takes care of the rest!
>
> For example, entering `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa-remote-ssh yourname@remotehost.yourcompany.com` in the input box would generate this entry:
>
> ```
> Host remotehost.yourcompany.com
>     User yourname
>     HostName another-host-fqdn-or-ip-goes-here
>     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-remote-ssh
> ```

Also possibly of interest to you: the `ProxyCommand` and `ProxyJump` fields for entries in ssh config files (see [`man ssh_config(5)`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)).

Comment: Yes but it fails. `Failed to parse remote port from server output`

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5111, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5099, https://stackoverflow.com/q/55979701/11107541