# VSCode Remote-SSH Connect Failed: after successfully connecting, it suddenly interrupted during work and has been unable to connect since then

Tags: vscode-remote-ssh

A few days ago, I was able to connect to the server normally, but suddenly I disconnected from the server. When reconnecting, the connection timeout was constantly displayed, so I increased the timeout to 600. Since then, I have been unable to connect to the server. I've tried various methods, but they haven't worked.

```
[10:05:17.412] Log Level: 2
[10:05:17.423] VS Code version: 1.82.2
[10:05:17.423] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.106.4
[10:05:17.423] win32 x64
[10:05:17.425] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+01", attempt 1
[10:05:17.425] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[10:05:17.426] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": false
[10:05:17.426] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true
[10:05:17.426] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"01":"linux"}
[10:05:17.426] "remote.SSH.path": D:\Input\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
[10:05:17.426] "remote.SSH.configFile": C:\Users\86182\.ssh\config
[10:05:17.426] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[10:05:17.426] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[10:05:17.427] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[10:05:17.427] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[10:05:17.427] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true
[10:05:17.428] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[10:05:17.429] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[10:05:17.429] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[10:05:17.429] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[10:05:17.429] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[10:05:17.429] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[10:05:17.433] SSH Resolver called for host: 01
[10:05:17.433] Setting up SSH remote "01"
[10:05:17.437] Using commit id "abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d" and quality "stable" for server
[10:05:17.440] Install and start server if needed
[10:05:17.444] Checking ssh with "D:\Input\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe -V"
[10:05:17.490] > OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020

[10:05:17.493] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\86182\.ssh\config"
[10:05:17.494] Running script with connection command: "D:\Input\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe" -T -D 58156 -F "C:\Users\86182\.ssh\config" 01 bash
[10:05:17.497] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[10:05:38.842] > ssh: connect to host region-42.seetacloud.com port 21777: Connection timed out
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[10:05:38.842] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[10:05:38.860] > ssh: connect to host region-42.seetacloud.com port 21777: Connection timed out
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
[10:05:40.135] "install" terminal command done
[10:05:40.136] Install terminal quit with output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[10:05:40.136] Received install output: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[10:05:40.136] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[10:05:40.138] Resolver error: Error: 
    at g.Create (c:\Users\86182\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.4\out\extension.js:2:637879)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\86182\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.4\out\extension.js:2:635279)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\86182\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.4\out\extension.js:2:756878)
    at async c:\Users\86182\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.4\out\extension.js:2:717470
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\86182\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.4\out\extension.js:2:720723)
    at async C (c:\Users\86182\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.4\out\extension.js:2:714384)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\86182\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.4\out\extension.js:2:718119)
    at async c:\Users\86182\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.4\out\extension.js:2:901789
[10:05:40.142] ------
```

I try to change timeout to 600, and delete 'know_hosts' file, but didn't work

system: win 10

server: linux

vscode version: 1.82.2

remote-ssh version: 0.106.4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979701/how-do-i-resolve-failed-to-parse-remote-port-from-server Check this out, it works for me.